# Can I have an MVC 4 Controller that uses a number as it's name?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, controllers

Sorry if this is a total noob question, but I'm trying to create controllers that are specific to a "year" for display of content.

When I try and create a "2015Controller" it inserts an underscore in front of the number and subsequently the view name as well. (Not the friendly url I was looking for.)

Maybe I'm being a complete dope and have been missing the boat on this, but I'd like to segregate the content into year based page displays as I have multiple years of content I'd like to have accessible via simple urls.

Comment: You can map any part of an URL to a controller name, action name or parameter name - not just in this particular order. So you can map your `/2014/` URL segment to anything, not just a controller name (I would map to a method's parameter). Can you show examples of your URLs?

Comment: Are you expecting your controllers to vary wildly from one year to the next, or do you just want to be able to pass in a year by using a URL like `http://mydomain/2015/Page`?

Comment: Content does vary by year as it's a community theater website, so I'd like to be able to use the mydomain/2015/page process.

Comment: @WorkingMan Then you can use e.g. `routes.MapRoute(null, "{year}/{action}", new { controller = "YourOnlyControllerNameHere", action = "Page"})`, and then define action `Page(string Year)` in your controller.

Comment: @GSerg - Thanks, I was thinking that some type of routing would be the way that I had to go, was trying to take an easier "route" to the end problem. (Tough teaching old dogs... -grin-) Thanks for the input on this, I didn't expect such quick responses!

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

I can say with a high degree of certainty that you should *not* be creating a new controller every year. That would give you a tremendous maintenance burden and bloated code (you'd have to create a new controller and a new controller class every year).

You should create a small set of controllers (maybe even just one), add the ability to pass in the year via the URL, and design them to dynamically load and provide content based on the specified year.

Here's how you can accomplish the "pass in the year via the URL" part.

Add this as the first route in RouteConfig.cs:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Year",
    url: "{year}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new {controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional},
    constraints: new{ year = @"\d{4}" });
```

This tells the routing module that any time a URL comes in that starts with 4 digits, it should send that request to the `Home` controller (you can change that if you want to), and pass those 4 digits as a routing value called `year`.

Then, in your `HomeController`, you can just go ahead and add `year` as a parameter in your actions:

```
public ActionResult Index(string year)
{
    // use year to fetch and prepare content
    return View();
}

public ActionResult Schedule(string year)
{
    // use year to fetch and prepare content
    return View();
}
```

So if a visitor navigates to `http://mydomain/2015` or `http://mydomain/2015/Index`, that request will be sent to the `Index` action with a `year` value of `2015`. If a visitor navigates to `http://mydomain/2016/Schedule`, that request will be sent to the `Schedule` action with a `year` value of `2016`.

So with that, you should be all set. If you want to differentiate between views based on the year, you can add multiple views, and just pass the needed values to the `View()` helper to show the view you want.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no connection between content and logic for each year, use Areas. Make a 2014 Area, a 2015 Area etc.

Areas are well documented on the Microsoft asp.net site

Answer (score 0):

thanks for all the help. I ended up going with "areas" as it made a bit more sense to me personally. Each year has a limited amount of content in it and it allows me to see things structure that I'm comfortable with.

Work for me will have to progress on the mapping process. I don't quite have it down and it turned out to be a bit frustrating when I'm pressed for time in development.

This site is amazing for all the information that I've gotten from it, thanks so much!